# Laravel pass collection to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to pass a collection to the view but I'm not getting anything.

The page renders blank

```
$companies = Companies::where('key',$key);
return View('view.name', compact('companies'));
```

In the blade I have

```
@foreach($companies as #company)

  {{$company->anything}}

@endforeach
```

The result is

> Error: Trying to get property 'anything' of non-object

From what I found this should work, please let me know what I`m doing wrong

Thanks for your help

Comment: you forgot ->get() $companies = Companies::where('key',$key)->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `->get()` to get the collection.

If you don't use `->get()` or `->first()`, your variable is still in 'QueryBuilder' format rather than 'Collection'.

```
$companies = Companies::where('key',$key)->get();

return view('view.name', compact('companies'));
```

---

A tip: You can use `dd()` in Laravel to be able to debug the variable.

For example: `dd($companies);`

Answer (score 1):

just:

```
$companies = Companies::where('key',$key)->get();
return View('view.name')->with('companies',$companies);
```

in blade:

```
@foreach($companies as $company)

{{$company->anything}}

@endforeach
```

if get any error use **dd($company)** to display $company has any array inside to make more foreach inside other

Comment: Thank you, I tried to mark both as the solution as both worked, but i can`t. And the other answer was first.